# Using noxDB, ParseString fails, but ParseFile is successful with the same JSON

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

Using noxDB on the IBM i in an RPG program, ParseString fails, but ParseFile is successful with the same JSON.

Please see the example below. Is ParseString unable to handle arrays? If so, is there a workaround?

In example1, json_Error(pJson) returns true.
Here is the error message:

> Invalid token at (1:101) token number: 5. Was expecting an ','
> but got a { near

In example2, json_Error(pJson) returns false.

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// example1
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dcl-Proc example1;
 
    Dcl-S pJson       Pointer;
    Dcl-S msg         varchar(256);
 
    pJson = json_parseString('            -
      {                                   -
    "people":[                        -
        {                         -
            "name":"John",    -
            "age":23,         -
        },                        -
         {                                -
            "name":"David",   -
            "age":25,         -
        }                         -
    ]                                 -
      }                                   -
    ');
 
    If json_Error(pJson) ;
        msg = json_Message(pJson);
        myTrace (msg :pJson);
        json_delete(pJson);
        Return;
    EndIf;
 
    myTrace ('After the parse: ':pJson);
 
    json_delete (pJson);
 
End-Proc;
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// example2
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dcl-Proc example2;
 
    Dcl-S pJson       Pointer;
    Dcl-S msg         varchar(256);
 
    pJson = json_ParseFile ('./example2.json');
    If json_Error(pJson) ;
        msg = json_Message(pJson);
        myTrace (msg :pJson);
        json_delete(pJson);
        Return;
    EndIf;
 
    myTrace ('After the parse: ':pJson);
 
    json_delete (pJson);
 
End-Proc;
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't include the stream file, but I suspect something is different...

I've not used noxDb, but I wouldn't expect json_parseString() to work any different than json_ParseFile().  Not sure if anyone here on SO is could to have any experience with noxDb.  You might try the [Midrange RPG mailing list](https://lists.midrange.com/mailman/listinfo/rpg400-l) or the [noxDB github](https://github.com/sitemule/noxDB).  Actually, looking at the source of noxDb json_ParseFile simply reads the entire file and passes it to json_ParseString().  So yeah..something is different.

Position 101 is the opening `{` for the first person as far as I can tell.

I'd recommend declaring a string variable and passing that into json_parseString() rather than the constant value you have now.  That will allow to to inspect the value via debug or just with a DSPLY.

**EDIT**
Note that the `,` after age is technically not valid.  Though some JSON parsers don't seem to care.

Personally, I stay away from continuing literals across lines.  I'd do it this way.

```
jsonData 
  = '{'
     + '"people":['
     +       '{"name":"John","age":23},'
     +       '{"name":"David","age":25}'
     +    ']'
     + '}';

pJson = json_parseString(jsonData);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Here is the content of the stream file:
{
 "person": [{
   "name": "John",
   "age": 23
  },
  {
   "name": "David",
   "age": 25
  }
 ]
}

Comment: @ray there seems to be a difference, particularly the stream file doesn't have the invalid `,` after age.  See edits

Comment: Great catch on the invalid comma. I simplified the JSON and missed removing the commas after the ages. I followed your suggestion and declared a variable and corrected the JSON, but I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: only other suggestion I have is to check the hex value of the variable in debug, `eval jsonData:h`  I've seen some unexplainable errors that turned out to be non-display characters.